# Second highest score

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Sample Input

```
5
2 3 6 6 5
```

## Sample Output

```
5
```

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "solution.py", line 2, in <module>
       li=[input() for i in range(n)]
     File "solution.py", line 2, in <listcomp>
       li=[input() for i in range(n)]
   EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

When I write this code in pyCharm, it works properly but when I write this code in Hackerrank.com, it showes me error.

```
n = int(input())
li=[input() for i in range(n)]

mx =  (max(li)) # it gives max number from list
li.remove(mx) # then i remove max no from the list
sec_mx = max(li) # now the second max is the new_max as you all knows
print(sec_mx)
```

Comment: try `li = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply sort list and you can access 2nd largest number from as last 2nd index i.e., -2

```
li = [12, 45, 45, 2, 41, 31, 10, 8, 6, 4]
print(sorted(set(li))[-2])
```

OR

```
sorted_list = sorted(set(li), reverse=True)
print(sorted_list[1])
```

Comment: That won't work for duplicate elements, which OP has.

Comment: given question [2, 3, 6, 6, 5 ] o/p:- 5 he is ignoring duplicates

Comment: Nusrath Thanks ,,, it's working now ,, BTW all are right but it's working on hackerrank.com ,, thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the input in a list, you can use a verbose:

```
scores = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5]

scores.sort(reverse = True)
max = scores[0]
second_best = scores[scores.count(max)]

print(second_best) #=> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` reads until you hit a newline. This works for the first line, since it's a single integer followed by a newline, but not for the second, since the separator is now a space. The reason that it works in pyCharm is most likely that you are separating your input with newlines, contrary to what the website is providing you.

You are probably looking for something more like

```
li = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Notice that you need to convert all the elements to `int` before you can meaningfully call `max` on the list. Otherwise, you will nee doing a lexicographixal comparison of strings, which will give unexpected results for numbers with more than one digit.

One other thing to be aware of is that `list.remove` only removes the first occurrence of the maximum. This means that your code, even if corrected to remove the error, will produce 6 rather than 5.

I can think of a number of ways of getting around this:

1. Keep removing the first maximum until you get an error.
2. Sort `li` in reverse order. Return the first element that does not equal `li[0]`.
3. Use bisection on a pre-sorted list:

   ```
   from bisect import bisect_left
   ...
   li.sort()
   ind = bisect_left(li, li[-1]) - 1
   second_max = li[ind]
   ```

Comment: sir you solution is definitely correct but mine also and all these are working on pyCharm too but don't know why error showing on hackerrank.com . btw thanks for help

Comment: and sir max() function works on input() too which gives string , no need to convert into integer format

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Here's an example in IDEOne: https://ideone.com/qsbYl8

Comment: Ohh Sorry Sir , You Are Right